# Four sequences with similar pattern of beginning

Tags: number-sequence

Determine the missing number
in the sequences below
$7, 9, 13, 17, ?, 29,... \\
6, 8, ?, 16, 24, 28,...$

$8, 11, 29, 51, 125, ?, 293,... \\
9, 11, 30, 51, 126, ?, 294,...$

I apologize for the simultaneous quantity, but I believe that the pairs have a similar pattern of beginning, so that resolving one will solve the others. Am I right?
These terms are important results to proceed with the solution of some integrals present in
[(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (Problem Books in Mathematics) (English Edition)](https://www.amazon.com.br/Impossible-Integrals-Problem-Mathematics-English-ebook/dp/B07YM2W66F/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=%28Almost%29+Impossible+Integrals%2C+Sums%2C+and+Series&qid=1605455591&sr=8-1)

Comment: To be clear, you want us to find the next terms in the sequences, not the terms represented by question marks?

Comment: @bobble The first sentence says "determine the missing number", therefore I'd assume you have to find the number represented by the question mark.

Comment: When I posted my first comment it said to find the "next terms", and it has been edited since to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the last two sequences should be

> 171 and 171

Because

> Hidden are the primes (in correct order) squared +4 or squared +2, for the first sequence.  And the only thing that is different with the second sequence is +5 instead of +4. So in both cases we get the same answer.

So we get

> $2^2 + 4 = 8, 3^2 + 2 = 11, 5^2 + 4 = 29, ...., 13^2 + 2 = 171,....$ and $2^2 + 5 = 9, 3^2 + 2 = 11, 5^2 + 5 = 30, ...., 13^2 + 2 = 171,.... $

Comment: Great find... and a funny coincidence too considering your name!

Answer (score 4):

**Partial Answer**

First two sequences

> If $p_n$ is the sequence of prime numbers, then the $n$th term of the first sequence is $2p_n+3$ and the second sequence is $2p_n+2$ so the complete sequences are $$7, 9, 13, 17, 25, 29,...$$ $$6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 28,...$$